# Ambiguous tag [ses]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The tag [ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ses) seems ambiguous. There are only 30 questions tagged with it, most are about [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses), but in a few it's about something different.

I'd suggest to clean up the few questions and make it a synonym of [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses), I lack the reputation for it.

**Update:**

I went through all questions tagged with [ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ses), all but three were about [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses) so I retagged them accordingly. The remaining three were all about Sitecore E-Commerce Services, so I created a new tag for it [sitecore-ecommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sitecore-ecommerce) (sitecore-ecommerce-services was too long) and retagged them as well.

Now that the tag [ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ses) is not used anymore IM it would be best to delete it, since it doesn't really serve a purpose.

Comment: Good work. The system automatically deletes unused tags.

Comment: 4 years later, there's 104 questions in the tag, [88 of which already have a amazon tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bses%5D+%5Bamazon*%5D++is%3Aq&mixed=0), and most of the remaining need one.

Answer (score 1):

Update after 4 years.

[ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ses) had come up again, and had 112 questions. The tag wiki was:

> Use emacs-ses or amazon-ses tags.

which itself mentions the ambiguous nature of the tag. There were [exactly 6 questions which did not have any of the Amazon SES related tags/words](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bses%5D+-%22amazon%22+-%22aws%22+is%3Aq+-%5Bamazon*%5D&mixed=0). Amongst them:

- 1 was related to SES using [boto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/boto), which is related to Amazon, so I left it as is.
- 1 was related to [nodeJS SES](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41628485/4099593), I removed the tag from the question.
- 2 were related to SES using PHP, [1 of which was using Amazon](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39328420/4099593), so I left it. [The other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53185963/4099593) was a bit ambiguous, so I removed the tag.
- 1 was using Magento Integration, again related to Amazon, so I left it.
- 1 was tagged R, and was something completely different, so I removed the tag.

Now, there are 109 questions that were totally related to [ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ses). I would usually leave similar situation tags alone, as users are using the tag correctly to identify one topic, and is therefore not ambiguous. However, in this case, there already is a well defined, sponsored and curated tag, [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses). Therefore, given the issue of double tags, I added [ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ses) as a synonym for [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses).