# Tag Synonym [amazon-ses] and [aws-ses]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonym-process

I found two tags [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses) and [aws-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ses) currently being used for [Amazon-Simple Email Service](https://aws.amazon.com/ses) and none of them is synonym of the other.

It looks like earlier the same issue was with [ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ses) (now: `Simple Emacs Spreadsheet`) and which was [solved](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269144/2873538) by retagging [ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ses) (earlier: `Simple Email Service`) questions with [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses).

What would be the best way to handle [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses) and [aws-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ses) and who could possibly do it?

Comment: There's no questions in the aws-ses tag

Comment: @TinyGiant At the time of posting this question, there were, someone [retagged](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/39315070/revisions) them? And what should be done now with [tag:aws-ses]?

Comment: It will be cleaned up automatically at 3:00 utc., then it will require someone with the create tags privilege to create it again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> There's no questions in the aws-ses tag

:P There were only 14 or so questions in the tag when I looked yesterday. I retagged those. It looks like Tiny Giant had already retagged some earlier.

As was said, the tag should be gone now, or whenever the automatic clean-up script gets to it. As long as nobody with the [Create Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags) privilege messes up and recreates it, we should be fine.

Comment: Now the tag [tag:aws-ses] is gone. But if someone recreates it in future, I think it should be marked as the synonym of [tag:amazon-ses].

Comment: [This](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/362739/repeat-question-tag-synonym-amazon-ses-and-aws-ses) is why you shouldn't just remove tags that have common acronyms just because it is easier.  It **will** get recreated.  This should have been made a synonym, not burninated.