# Repeat question - tag synonym [amazon-ses] and [aws-ses]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

This was raised previously, but it was not addressed and came back again:

*[Tag Synonym [amazon-ses] and [aws-ses]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333834/tag-synonym-amazon-ses-and-aws-ses)*

There are 23 [aws-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aws-ses) questions that should be merged into [amazon-ses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ses) (700+ questions).

Comment: So someone with a high enough score in the tag should [suggest](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/amazon-ses/synonyms) a synonym, that others should vote for.

Comment: Unfortunately that someone needs 5+ points on amazon-ses tag, which I don't have

Comment: Merged and syn. created.

Comment: Ahhh nope - we're all good - no worries :)